# Potential forms of verbs that have gained a spontaneous meaning (e.g., 泣ける)

Tags: grammar, potential-form

## English

I was thinking about the word 泣ける and how it has a usage where it's not really a potential — in particular its usage where it gets used to mean something was moving and caused the speaker to cry.

Pulling up the definition in 明鏡, there's the following:

> な・ける【泣ける】
> 〔自下一〕
> ①〔「泣く」の可能形〕泣くことができる。
> 　　「悲しくとも泣くにー・けない」
> **②〔①から〕感動のあまり涙が出てくる。また、泣きたくなるほど感動する。**
> 　　「ひとりでにー・けてくる」
> 　　「ー話じゃないか」

This entry suggests that the etymology is indeed from the potential form, and it's not that there was originally an intransitive verb with this meaning.

I was curious if there are any other verbs where the potential form can be used with this sort of spontaneous (自発) intransitive meaning, or otherwise more information about this phenomenon.

(This is slightly reminiscent of 見える and 聞こえる, but those are not standard potential forms and were formed much longer ago than this usage of 泣ける.)

## Japanese

「泣ける」という言葉について考えていたら、本来の可能の意味の他に、可能の意味があまり入っていない使い方もあることに気付きました。明鏡では②です。

> な・ける【泣ける】
> 〔自下一〕
> ①〔「泣く」の可能形〕泣くことができる。
> 　　「悲しくとも泣くにー・けない」
> **②〔①から〕感動のあまり涙が出てくる。また、泣きたくなるほど感動する。**
> 　　「ひとりでにー・けてくる」
> 　　「ー話じゃないか」

この項目から考えると、②の語源は「泣く」の可能形であって、別の自動詞に由来しているわけではないようです。

こういった自発っぽい意味を持った可能動詞は他にもあるでしょうか。またはこの現象について何か情報はあるでしょうか。

（「見える」や「聞こえる」も思い出されますが、「見る」と「聞く」の一般的な可能形ではないことと、昔から使われている動詞だという点で少し違うかなと思いました。）

Answer (score 6):

「笑える」は多分学校で習うと思います。早速それで検索して見ると「教えてgoo」にも類似の質問があった様です。

[「難しくて泣ける」「思わず笑える」の文法的説明](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/8761448.html)

以下回答No2.からの抜粋です。

> 自発か可能かは、前後の関係で決まると認識しています。

- 自発 ＝ 自然とそういう状況になる
- 可能 ＝ 意思を持ってすればそういう状況になる

1.「数学の授業が難しくて泣ける」: 泣きたい意思はないはず・・・自発

---

2.「思わず笑える」・・・思わずだから、笑う意思にかかわらず・・自発

> 例、（落語の）あそこは笑える・・・可能・・笑いを得たくて落語を聞く

論文では、

[現代日本語の自発に関する研究 ――受身・可能との関連を視野に入れて――](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=2ahUKEwj8gPKfp7jkAhUmBKYKHfB3ArEQFjAKegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnagoya.repo.nii.ac.jp%2F%3Faction%3Drepository_uri%26item_id%3D24672%26file_id%3D17%26file_no%3D3&usg=AOvVaw0Nrm4Gd7CSDN66eVP64kUY)

*第4章p63以降　*可能動詞による自発表現　――
可能動詞の意味分化を契機として発生した可能性について――*

で挙げられている例文にも、

***現代語において、動詞「笑う」の可能動詞「笑える」は、 可能だけでなく自発にも解釈
されることがある。***

> (5) 時間が経って悲しみも癒え、ようやく笑えるようになった。 〔可能〕
>
> (6) ひょうきんな彼を見ていると、自然と笑えてくる。 〔自発〕